# Downloading text file when CTRL is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to download text files, when CTRL (17) is pressed , its working fine but now my code working when CTRL is pressed, then add atributes to 'download' button, and then starting the download.

There is any solution to do: when CTRL is pressed then start the download without need to press 'download' button?

```
  else if (e.originalEvent.keyCode === 17)
        {
            var file_name = e.target.innerText;

            var path = "files/" + file_name;

            var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();

            rawFile.open("GET", path, false);

            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;

                var fileName = file_name;
                var myFile = new Blob([allText], {type: 'text/plain'});

                window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(myFile));
                document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('download', fileName);
            };
            rawFile.send(null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var file_name = e.target.innerText;

        var path = "files/" + file_name;

        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();

        rawFile.open("GET", path, false);

        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            var allText = rawFile.responseText;

            var fileName = file_name;
            var myFile = new Blob([allText], {type: 'text/plain'});

            window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(myFile));
            document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('download', fileName);

            $("#download").click();//click here

        };
        rawFile.send(null);
```

You can click that item programmatically. You can do it after set attributes.

Comment: There is no error, its just the code not runing it, only when i press Download link

Comment: You need to provide more code. We need to see how the click handler is getting added to the button.

Comment: I have no more code, only one more HTML file, this one have 1 row: <a href="" id="download">Download</a> thats all

Comment: maybe $("#download").click(); not working cause now i see i use <a> instead of <button>, there is any way to trigger <a>?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone care, here is the answer:

```
document.getElementById("download").click();
```

Thank you btw :)